# Get position of a specific id in an order by query

Tags: c#

I need to do a query in c# to get the position of a specific id, in a table order by a date.

My table structure

```
IdAirport   bigint
IdUser  int
AddedDate   datetime
```

Data:

```
2   5126    2014-10-23 14:54:32.677
2   5127    2014-10-23 14:55:32.677
1   5128    2014-10-23 14:56:32.677
2   5129    2014-10-23 14:57:32.677
```

For example, i need to know in which position is the IdUser=5129, in the IdAirport=2, order by AddedDate asc. (The result in this case will be 3).

Edit:

im using iQueryables like this:

AirPort airport = (for airport as context.Airport select airport).FirstOrDefault();

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What data access technology are you using?

Comment: Are you looking for LINQ query for list of your objects?

Comment: Using the Where method with the index overload...

Comment: MS Sql server? In that case use the Rownumber in your query. ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: Take a look at the linq `.Select` method extension overloads. And it would have been nice if you showed us what you've tried already.

Comment: I've added the technology im using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ: If you want to find the index of an element within an arbitrary order you can use `OrderBy()`, `TakeWhile()` and `Count()`.

```
 db.records.Where(x => x.IdAirport == airportId)
           .OrderBy(x => x.AddedDate)
           .TakeWhile(x => x.IdUser != userId)
           .Count() + 1;
```

Comment: Great answer, just to a small correction. The takeWhile gives me the count of element until mine, so the position of my element is that number + 1.

Comment: Normally we would do zero-based positions but I see from your example, now, that you wanted it one-based. OK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick one :

```
public class test
{
    public int IdAirport;
    public int IdUser;
    public DateTime AddedDate;

    public test(int IdAirport, int IdUser, DateTime AddedDate)
    {
        this.IdAirport = IdAirport;
        this.IdUser = IdUser;
        this.AddedDate = AddedDate;
    }
}

    void Main()
    {
        List<test> tests = new List<test>()
    {
    new test(2,   5126,    DateTime.Parse("2014-10-23 14:54:32.677")),
    new test(2,   5127,    DateTime.Parse("2014-10-23 14:55:32.677")),
    new test(1 ,  5128 ,   DateTime.Parse("2014-10-23 14:56:32.677")),
    new test(2  , 5129  ,  DateTime.Parse("2014-10-23 14:57:32.677"))
    };

        var r = tests
        .Where(t => t.IdAirport == 2)
        .OrderBy(t => t.AddedDate)
        .TakeWhile(t => t.IdUser != 5129)
        .Count() + 1;

        Console.WriteLine(r);
    }
```

It keeps the exact order of your own list. You can modify Where/OrderBy if you wish, the interesting part is in the "TakeWhile/Count" use.

Should work fine but probably not very efficient for long lists.

edit : seems to be the same as Ian Mercer. But the "+ 1" in my own sample is needed since TakeWhile will return the number of skipped items, hence not the position of the good one. Or I didn't get well the issue.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz > sorry but you are wrong : the OP asked for the position of the expected item and humans count from 1, not 0. And in its own example it clearly states the expected value is 3. So (and I've just checked that) I gave the right answer, at least according to my understanding of the question.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I saw the 3 but I saw 5129 in the 4th (index 3) position. Didn't realize it was filtering by IdAirport.

Comment: No problem :). I am still not totally sure myself to have understood the OP's need clearly ;)

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you need:

```
dataTable.Rows.IndexOf(
    dataTable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(
    x => x["AddedDateColumn"]).First(
    x => (int)(x["IdUserColumn"]) == 5129));
```

Comment: How do you know he is using datatables?

Comment: Just assumed because the question is only tagged [c#].

Comment: Ok, now this answer makes no sense. He wasn't pshychic after all =(